# How to deal with spam in a QA site where anon answers are allowed?

Tags: wordpress, spam, spam-prevention

I have a Question Answer website. I had allowed anonymous users to post answers to question on the site.

Today I got 14 answers to a one question on my site, My site isn't all that famous and all. Its very new and build with Wordpress. I was shocked to see what these answers were... they were all spams.

Below is 3 out of 14 answers I had found on this question. As you can make out they are not at all related to the question which was "Difference between Encapsulation and Abstraction"

[image]

I have made the "add question" part private, meaning user needs to sign up to ask a question, for the answer part I thought I should allow anonymous answers.

I am confused about this now. Is there a way to deal with this ? I'm just hoping this question is fit for stackoverflow.com.

Please advice.

Comment: google for: spam filter, captcha, ...

Comment: are these comments auto posted or some one manually puts one by one. If its a person then he ll fill out the captcha as well right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to add some form of captcha or anti-bot system to stop the bots posting random spam in the comments section.

I would recommend using a 3rd party plugin such as [SI Captcha](http://wordpress.org/plugins/si-captcha-for-wordpress/) which is a widely used, well documented and easy to install & implement.

Alternatively, you could start blocking IPs, IP ranges or email addresses but you would have to keep doing this constantly whereas using a plugin like above would mean that the whole process is automated.

If you are using an outside commenting system such as Disqus, then you will need to let us know so we can find alternatives for you.